# Why do I get different result when trying to solve the same problem with one Solve and two Solve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

first way which gives out the result very quickly:

```
sol1 = Solve[a12 a21==(a12+ra t1)(a21-t2) && b21 b12 == (b21+rb t2)(b12-t3), {t2,t3}]

Solve[D[(t3-t1 /. sol1), t1]==0, t1]
```

second way which outputs empty result:

```
Solve[a12 a21==(a12+ra t1)(a21-t2) && b21 b12 == (b21+rb t2)(b12-t3) && D[t3-t1, t1]==0, {t1,t2,t3}]
```

What's the difference between the two ways except one is two step while the other is one step? How can I get the same result as the first way with only one Solve?

Comment: What should "D(t3-t1, t1)==0" mean?

Comment: @DanielHuber typo, should be `D[t3-t1, t1]==0`, fixed.

Comment: `D[t3-t1, t1]==0` gives `-1==0`

Comment: `Trace[Solve[a12 a21 == (a12 + ra t1) (a21 - t2) && b21 b12 == (b21 + rb t2) (b12 - t3) && D[t3 - t1, t1] == 0, {t1, t2, t3}]]`